# How to track a user activity in a wifi zone by smart handheld devices

Tags: android, network-protocols, ios8, data-link-layer

Few companies have developed Wi-Fi hubs that remember the MAC addresses they see. While doing so they worked on to find the MAC addresses  also known as hardware addresses or physical addresses. They uniquely identify an adapter on a LAN.

Now with ios8 for security reason they are coming with dynamic MAC Address.

http://techcrunch.com/2013/06/14/ios-7-eliminates-mac-address-as-tracking-option-signaling-final-push-towards-apples-own-ad-identifier-technology/

Now they have eliminated the MAC address tracking option.

I was looking a kind of solution where still we will be able to track the user . Say User A has visited the wifi zone A today and if he comes again after sometime(even month) i should be able to figure out that this is the same user who visited in the past.

On a very high note i think can we have some pattern saving with respect to user the pattern would consists of OS used in device and combination of other useful information with respect to OSI model or some protocol level information which would assure that the user can be tracked with device even without the usage of MAC address.

Comment: Are you asking about people who have agreed to be tracked and are running an app of yours (for example your own employees in a warehouse)?  Or are you looking to track and violate the privacy of everyone who walks by your location?

Comment: Sorry for not making myself clear. Yes for people who have agreed to be tracked. Thanks